# xcode recourses do not update on build

Tags: iphone, database, file, resources, xcode4

I have a sqlite db in my project and when I update the db with an external dbmanager I want it to rebuild in the simulator but it doesnt.
No wonder I didnt get the results I wanted :-)

But now I have to edit the file in library/app support/iphone simulator... (you know the way...).

If I remove the file from the project and add it with another name (and change the references in the code) the file is 0KB in the simulatorfolder (mentioned above).

Even after a clean and rebuild its still empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean and then build.
This should rebuild the app bundle and re-include all files from you project.

Comment: I've also been updating a sqlite database via an external tool. But cleaning all targets always does the trick for me. Are you coping the sqlite file to the document directory ?

Comment: It copies an empty db to the directory...? but now I edit the db in that directory directly...

Comment: As I understand you copy the empty database to your document directory. Then you edit it there? When you then copy that db file to your project to bundle it with you app it will not automaticly  override the current version if you have code that checks if the file exists. You could use some kind of version in the userdefaults to to check if the current db is up to date.

Comment: well... not exactly. Since the buildprocess didnt update the db I decided to copy it manually to the builddirectory and edit it there.
I dont want to do this but it was the only way to get it updated in the project. its not only the db that behaves like this. I wonder if it has to do anything with filevault. I have seen similar behaviour with some other apps that doesnt want to update settings from within apps.